# Python3 - Port forwarding using UPNP using sockets to make a peer to peer network

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, p2p, portforwarding, upnp

I've messed around with sockets for a while and in order to forward a port, I need to port forward on my router as well as open the port on my windows firewall. I'm trying to set up a peer to peer network using python3. I've heard that the only way to make this possible is to use UPNP. What packages would make this possible so that the peers don't need to configure their firewall or router? Thanks for your help <3

Comment: Please show us some code !

Comment: I'm asking for libraries, the code part I can handle